# Which service is started in method "internalRegister" of GCM?

Tags: android, android-c2dm, google-cloud-messaging

Below is the code from `internalRegister` method of `GCMRegistrar` class

```
static void internalRegister(Context context, String... senderIds) {
        if (senderIds == null || senderIds.length == 0 ) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("No senderIds");
        }
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(senderIds[0]);
        for (int i = 1; i < senderIds.length; i++) {
            builder.append(',').append(senderIds[i]);
        }
        String senders = builder.toString();
        Log.v(TAG, "Registering app "  + context.getPackageName() +
                " of senders " + senders);
        Intent intent = new Intent(GCMConstants.INTENT_TO_GCM_REGISTRATION);
        intent.setPackage(GSF_PACKAGE);
        intent.putExtra(GCMConstants.EXTRA_APPLICATION_PENDING_INTENT,
                PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(), 0));
        intent.putExtra(GCMConstants.EXTRA_SENDER, senders);
        context.startService(intent);
    }
```

In the last line of code it starts a service which is supposed to contact the GCM server. the GSM server in turn send a Broadcast `com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION` back. **Which service is this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The intent com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION is part of the Android OS since 2.2. In the old days, we call startService to this intent in order to register our devices with Google C2DM server. You can also do the same thing with GCM, without using the GCM client library.

See this migration guide and you'll know what I meant: http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/c2dm.html

For me, I skipped the GCM library altogether, and use the com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION intent directly to register.

Comment: My question which `service` are we starting?

Comment: That service is part of the Android OS, that we don't have access to the source code. When you start a service with the intent com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION, the Android OS will handle it and perform the C2DM/GCM registration with Google server. My guess is the Google Talk component is probably the one that owns this service.